# Upgrading Facebook.framework using plugin-x in cocos2d-x 3.3

Tags: ios, facebook, cocos2d-x, integration

I'm integrating Facebook SDK by using plugin-x in cocos2d-x 3.3
There are few issues with Facebook.framework/Headers soft link issues. (You can get the answer to resolve this with Googling.)
Eventually, now I can build cocos2d-x project with the Facebook plugin.

But I want to upgrade Facebook SDK from 2.1(inside of cocos2d-x 3.3) to 2.2 (latest one).

There is only one issue with

```
[FBSettings setsdkVersion:sdkVersion];
```

I've searched all versions of Facebook SDK but CANNOT find the method "    [FBSettings setsdkVersion:sdkVersion]". And also it doesn't make sense to set Facebook SDK version by myself.
But the version in cocos2d-x 3.3 includes FBSettings.h like below.

```
/*!
  @method
  @abstract Retrieve the current iOS SDK version.
*/
+ (NSString *)sdkVersion;

/*!
  @method

  @abstract Retrieve the current iOS SDK version.
*/
+ (void)setsdkVersion:(NSString*)version;
```

It has sdkVersion as getter for Facebook SDK version and also includes setsdkVersion with wrong method description.

Are they just made the empty method for setsdkVersion? or Is this official method that Facebook SDK has?

I can't find any reference about setsdkVersion method in FBSettings class in Google search result.

Anybody has idea?